# Pan sharpening using GDAL when pan band is on the same dataset

Tags: python, gdal, bash, pansharpening

I have tiff with 5 bands, when the  fifth band is the panchromatic band.
I want to use the 5th band in order to pan-sharp the image.
I have used [this tutorial](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_pansharpen.html) in order to do the process. As I have all the bands, including the pan band, on the same dataset, I have written the following:

```
#band 5 is the PAN band
gdal_pansharpen.py folder/img.tiff,band=5 folder/img.tiff,band=4 folder/img.tiff,band=3 folder/img.tiff,band=2 folder/img.tiff,band=1 pansharpened_out.tif
```

but that raises error:

> folder/img.tiff,band=5: No such file or directory

I think that the problem is with the way I tell gdal that band 5 is the pan band, because if I remove  it, the function run, However, the fact that is run is not helping me much before I couldn't make it pan-sharpened with the correct band.

I wonder, if the only way to do this is by saving band5 separatly, or, if there is any way I can pan-sharpen the image with band 5 without "separate" it from the other bands.

**So my end goal is to pan sharpen bands 1,2,3 and 4 using band 5.**

Comment: Maybe a cheap workaround would be to separate the 5th band into a VRT https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html.

Comment: From the doc you linked to "*<pan_dataset> Dataset with panchromatic band (**first band will be used**).*"  So @user30184's suggestion of creating a separate VRT of band 5 should work. However, if your band 5 is in the same tif as the multispectral bands, it will be the same resolution so there's not really much point trying to use it to pansharpen.